# Code not working the way that I want it to (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def operator_updater(all_operators):
    for operator in all_operators:
        print(operator, sep=' ', end='', flush=True)

all_operators = ['|+|', '|-|', '|x|', '|/|']
op = input(f"Input Operator {operator_updater(all_operators)}: ")
```

#I want it to print like this Input Operator |+| |-| |x| |/|:

#But this is the result --> |+| |-| |x| |/| Input Operator None:

Comment: Please use a title that summarises the content of your question. "Code not working the way I want it to" could apply to most of the questions on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator_updater` function is printing the values before it returns. It also doesn't return anything, that's why you're seeing None. You could do something like this, but there's probably better ways to go about it.

```
def operator_updater(all_operators):
    result = ''
    for operator in all_operators:
        result += operator + ' '
    return result[:-1]


all_operators = ['|+|', '|-|', '|x|', '|/|']
op = input(f"Input Operator {operator_updater(all_operators)}: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from `operator_updater` so you see the None. Instead, you're printing, so you'll see that before. You'll want to return the string so it shows up on the input line. Obviously in this case, you'll need:

```
return ' '.join(all_operators)
```